# Error when triggering process Model

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

I am deploying my java Application(using JBPM and Drools) on JBoss. When process Model is triggered,i am facing the following error.

```
17:01:10,850 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-83) Starting the sprinkler

17:01:10,940 WARN  [org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService] (Thread-83) Could not commit session: org.jbpm.workflow.instance.WorkflowRuntimeException: [com.sample.FireAlarm.bpmn:1 - TurnOnSprinkler:2] -- Error initialising KeyStore: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:135) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:66) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:43) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:35) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:222) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:358) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:189) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:171) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.startProcess(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1580) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:366) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:121) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:40) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:36) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService$TransactionInterceptor.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:527) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:73) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:375) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:232) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at com.aricent.bpm.util.ProcessUtil.startProcess(ProcessUtil.java:19) [classes:]
    at com.aricent.bpm.model.Device.setSprinkler(Device.java:62) [classes:]
    at defaultpkg.Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579.defaultConsequence(Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579.java:8)
    at defaultpkg.Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at defaultpkg.Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.core.rule.Rule$SafeConsequence$1.run(Rule.java:863) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.drools.core.rule.Rule$SafeConsequence.evaluate(Rule.java:860) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1016) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:128) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:70) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:935) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1200) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:957) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:931) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:256) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.FireAllRulesCommand.execute(FireAllRulesCommand.java:106) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.FireAllRulesCommand.execute(FireAllRulesCommand.java:32) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:36) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService$TransactionInterceptor.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:527) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:73) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:375) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:258) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at com.aricent.bpm.util.EventReceiver.run(EventReceiver.java:18) [classes:]
Caused by: org.drools.core.RuntimeDroolsException: Error initialising KeyStore: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at org.drools.core.util.KeyStoreHelper.<init>(KeyStoreHelper.java:93) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.PersisterHelper.sign(PersisterHelper.java:230) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.PersisterHelper.writeToStreamWithHeader(PersisterHelper.java:203) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.marshalling.impl.ProtobufProcessMarshaller.writeWorkItem(ProtobufProcessMarshaller.java:285) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.writeWorkItem(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:922) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo.update(WorkItemInfo.java:159) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:47) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:124) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(SecurityManager.java:1269) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:623) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.drools.core.util.KeyStoreHelper.<init>(KeyStoreHelper.java:69) [drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    ... 55 more

17:01:11,160 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83) org.jbpm.workflow.instance.WorkflowRuntimeException: [com.sample.FireAlarm.bpmn:1 - TurnOnSprinkler:2] -- Error initialising KeyStore: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")

17:01:11,161 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:135)

17:01:11,162 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155)

17:01:11,185 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337)

17:01:11,186 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296)

17:01:11,186 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:66)

17:01:11,187 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:43)

17:01:11,187 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155)

17:01:11,187 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:35)

17:01:11,188 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:222)

17:01:11,188 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:358)

17:01:11,192 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:189)

17:01:11,193 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:171)

17:01:11,194 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.startProcess(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1580)

17:01:11,196 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:366)

17:01:11,199 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:121)

17:01:11,199 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:40)

17:01:11,200 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:36)

17:01:11,200 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)

17:01:11,220 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService$TransactionInterceptor.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:527)

17:01:11,221 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)

17:01:11,221 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:73)

17:01:11,221 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:375)

17:01:11,227 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:232)

17:01:11,227 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at com.aricent.bpm.util.ProcessUtil.startProcess(ProcessUtil.java:19)

17:01:11,228 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at com.aricent.bpm.model.Device.setSprinkler(Device.java:62)

17:01:11,228 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at defaultpkg.Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579.defaultConsequence(Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579.java:8)

17:01:11,247 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at defaultpkg.Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)

17:01:11,248 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at defaultpkg.Rule_start_the_sprinkler901187579DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)

17:01:11,248 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.rule.Rule$SafeConsequence$1.run(Rule.java:863)

17:01:11,248 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

17:01:11,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.rule.Rule$SafeConsequence.evaluate(Rule.java:860)

17:01:11,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1016)

17:01:11,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:128)

17:01:11,253 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:70)

17:01:11,259 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:935)

17:01:11,259 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1200)

17:01:11,259 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:957)

17:01:11,260 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:931)

17:01:11,265 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:256)

17:01:11,265 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.FireAllRulesCommand.execute(FireAllRulesCommand.java:106)

17:01:11,265 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.FireAllRulesCommand.execute(FireAllRulesCommand.java:32)

17:01:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:36)

17:01:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)

17:01:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService$TransactionInterceptor.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:527)

17:01:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)

17:01:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:73)

17:01:11,291 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:375)

17:01:11,291 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:258)

17:01:11,292 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at com.aricent.bpm.util.EventReceiver.run(EventReceiver.java:18)

17:01:11,292 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83) Caused by: org.drools.core.RuntimeDroolsException: Error initialising KeyStore: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")

17:01:11,299 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.util.KeyStoreHelper.<init>(KeyStoreHelper.java:93)

17:01:11,299 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.PersisterHelper.sign(PersisterHelper.java:230)

17:01:11,299 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.PersisterHelper.writeToStreamWithHeader(PersisterHelper.java:203)

17:01:11,300 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.marshalling.impl.ProtobufProcessMarshaller.writeWorkItem(ProtobufProcessMarshaller.java:285)

17:01:11,324 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.writeWorkItem(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:922)

17:01:11,325 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo.update(WorkItemInfo.java:159)

17:01:11,325 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:47)

17:01:11,325 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:124)

17:01:11,326 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     ... 48 more

17:01:11,326 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83) Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")

17:01:11,326 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)

17:01:11,327 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)

17:01:11,331 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)

17:01:11,331 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(SecurityManager.java:1269)

17:01:11,331 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:623)

17:01:11,331 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     at org.drools.core.util.KeyStoreHelper.<init>(KeyStoreHelper.java:69)

17:01:11,351 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-83)     ... 55 more
```

Comment: looks like a permission error with your keystore. are you using https protocol?

Comment: No, i am using http protocol.when kie session(jbpm6) tries to execute the my process model, i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

issue is found.Issue is with kie.policy in my jboss/bin.

By default it is written with "read"
after updating PropertyPermission as follows in kie.policy.It resolved the error.

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*","read,write";